# Is creating a new array in a loop in Javascript a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, html5-canvas

Sometimes we need to use temporary array in a loop to store data. For example, when we need to deal with 2 dimension arrays. But I am not sure if it is a bad practice to create a new array in a loop, especially if I need to do it often, such as in animation.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    const temp = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        temp.push(j);
    }
    arr.push(temp);
}
```

If this is a variable I should be able to use a global variable and reassign value to it. So I have tried to use a global array and clear the array using `temp.length = 0` but then because the array's reference is stored the data will all become the last pushed values. I have also tried a global `const temp = new Set()` but then when I push the `temp` set into the `arr` array it will be `arr.push([...temp])`. So is it inevitable to create new array in such situation?

Comment: @Adam Have you tried that? I am not reassigning.  Read my title carefully. I am creating a new array.

Comment: Well if you want an array of 10000 arrays, then yes it definitely is inevitable to create 10000 arrays (and do that preferably in a loop). Whether having 1000s of arrays is a bad practice depends on the problem they are supposed to solve.

Comment: Whether it's an issue or not really depends on what you're actually doing, and if you've got an actual performance problem.  If you do, then you'd have to look at refactoring the code to see if there are any alternative structures, but as @Bergi said - if you need an array of arrays, you need to create them one way or another.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes I agree the first thing I need to think about is another data structure. But sometimes I am using other libraries so I have to stick to their data structure.

Comment: @Bergi, As I said in the question. The example is javascript animation, on the browser, etc.

Comment: If is is about arrays of length 10, I think it is not a big deal. Think about it, if you were not using arrays but strings of length 10, would you bother ?

Comment: @Alburkerk Yes it might be length of 10. But the data could be a bloated object with many properties that need to be changed.

Comment: Would you bother to give a more clear example of your animation (maybe a jsfiddle so we can see the animation, the code in practice) ? I think there won't be a general answer in Javascript for avoid creating arrays or arrays (then it would become standard). So you are only likely to receive an answer for your specific case

Comment: @newguy Animation needs only CSS, not javascript or even 10000 arrays. What are you really doing? Can you post your code?

Comment: @Alburkerk Sorry. That would be too much code. And I have actually revised the data structure whenever I face such situation. But I haven't done a jsPerf or profile it. I just always have such thoughts in mind but not sure if I should ask it here. Sometimes it is not so obvious.

Comment: @Bergi Canvas animation and WebGL.

Comment: @newguy Canvas is using a single large typed array for its data, not 10000 arrays. Not sure what you are doing with WebGL. Yes there might be use cases (e.g. particle animation) for lots of objects, and you should be fine as long as you don't (re)create those many objects on every frame.

Answer (score 0):

## Typed arrays

[TypedArrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) should always be the first option when you need an array. They offer massive performance and memory benefits over standard arrays.

The quickest way to create an array of numbers is

```
var i,j,b,a = [];
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i += 1) {
    a[i] = b = new Float64Array(10);
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j += 1) {
        b[j] = j;
    }
}
```

Which benchmarked at 634, a huge 5.5 times quicker than the fastest `Array` method

```
var i,j,b,a = [];
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i += 1) {
    a[i] = b = [];
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j += 1) {
        b[j] = j;
    }
}
```

Which benchmarked 3664 which is another  3.4 times quicker than

```
const arr = [...Array(10000)];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
  arr[i] = [...Array(10).keys()]
}
```

That benchmarks a sad 12352

Typed arrays are fixed size, and when declared they are pre filled with zero. They will never become sparse and if use well can eliminate GC overheads.

With [`Atomics`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics) and you can share them with workers via [`SharedArrayBuffers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer)(True sharing a shared array only has one address)

Though they are limited to Doubles, floats, signed and unsigned integers, they can hold any type of data (computers are just binary processing machines after all) and will give noticeable performance increases for any type of array work

### Is creating arrays in loops bad.

There nothing wrong with creating arrays in loops.